# Flatten List<Observable<X[]> into Observable<X[]>

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable

In my project i need to make subsequent calls to an API to retrieve summaries from different courses, and its all stored in a List like so:

```
List<Observable<Summaries[]>> summaries
```

Then, i need to perform an action on those observables, and im using something along this lines:

```
Observable
    .switchOnNext(Observable.from(summaries))
    .doOnNext(summaries -> { actionToBeDone() })
```

However, this performs the action for each Observable present in the list, and in the project implementation i am only able to execute the action to all at once, so my question is:

Is it possible to

```
List<Observable<Summaries[]>>
```

into

```
Observable<Summaries[]>
```

If not, is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Have you looked at `concat()` or `merge()`?

Comment: Yes, but with no success

Comment: I don't understand. Would you like to have an `Observable` with a single item of a big `Summaries[]` array which is made out of all of the other `Summaries[]` inside those input `Observable`s?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly it

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments, you still have to use `concat` for example, then `collect` into an `ArrayList` followed by a `toArray` `map`ping:

```
Observable.concat(summaries)
.collect(ArrayList::new, (list, summary) -> list.addAll(Arrays.asList(summary)))
.map(list -> list.toArray(new Summaries[list.size()]))
.subscribe(/* ... */);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! I just had to add Observable.concat(Observable.from(summaries)) (....). Thank you!